# Cocoalumberjack DDLogInfo() doesn`t show File, Linenumber and function name

Tags: cocoalumberjack

I'm using [CocoaLumberjack](https://github.com/CocoaLumberjack/CocoaLumberjack) in an iPhone project, to log some information.

I've followed the Getting started guide, and everything works fine, but there is one thing that bugs me: I could not able to log the file name, line number, function name. Is there a way to do that....

Can some one help me posting sample code snippet!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cocoa Lumberjack: how to show file and line number?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19137867/cocoa-lumberjack-how-to-show-file-and-line-number)

Comment: The question has already been asked and answered